# Filter list of items

Tags: backbone.js

I have a list of items and a query textfield. When I enter a query in the textfield, I want to filter the list of items based on the query. How can I do this?

In the view I added an event:

```
events: ->
    'submit #query_form'          : 'filterLinks'
```

This triggers a function where I first empty the list and then want to show only the items which meet the query criteria:

```
  filterLinks: ->
    query = $('#query').val()
    @collection.reset()
```

How can I filter the list?

Edit: This is the complete view:

```
  template: JST['links/index']

  initialize: ->
    @collection.on('reset', @render, this)
    @collection.on('add', @appendLink, this)

  events: ->
    'submit #new_link'            : 'createLink'
    'submit #query_form'          : 'filterLinks'

  render: ->
    $(@el).html(@template())
    @collection.each(@appendLink)
    this

  createLink: (event) ->
    event.preventDefault()
    @collection.create
      title:        $('#title').val()
      description:  $('#description').val()
      url:          $('#url').val()
      category:     $('#category').val()
      votes:        0
    $('#message').append('<div>Link has been added succesfully!</div>').fadeOut(5000)

  appendLink: (link) ->
    view = new Hotlynx.Views.Link(model: link)
    $('#all_links').append(view.render().el)

  filterLinks: ->
    alert($('#query').val())
    @collection.reset()
```

Comment: What does your view code look like?  You might want to leave the collection alone and re-render the view, only adding items that match the filter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use underscore's `filter` method to filter the collection and return only the results you want. See: http://underscorejs.org/#filter

Then you'd use the result of this filter to re-render the view that displays the items.

Answer (score 0):

You could just re-render and do something like this:

```
appendLink: (link) ->
    if( link.get('someAttribute') === this.filterValue)
        view = new Hotlynx.Views.Link(model: link)
        $('#all_links').append(view.render().el)
```